# Make Kivy TextInput Frames invisible but show text

Tags: python, kivy, textinput

I'm attempting to make the TextInput widgets "invisible" like you would by using

```
opacity: 0
```

However, I want the text inside the TextInput to show. If I use

```
opacity: 0
```

The TextInput widget and the text inside the widget is not visible, is there a way to "hide" the widget while still showing the text?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class ExampleScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ExampleManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
ExampleManager:
    ExampleScreen:

<ExampleScreen>:
    name: 'example_screen'
    TextInput:
        id: t_1
        text: 'Test text in input 1'
        size_hint: .5, .5
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .5}
        multiline: True
        readonly: True
        opacity: 0  ## If I remove this line both text edits are visible. 
                    ##You can test this by putting ## before opacity

        ## What I'm trying to do, is make the TextInput widget opaque so 
        ##that you can't see the frame and only the text is visible

    TextInput:
        id: t_2
        text: 'Test text in input 2'
        size_hint: .5, .5
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
        multiline: True
        readonly: True
        opacity: 0  ## If I remove this line both text edits are visible. 
                    ##You can test this by putting ## before opacity

        ## What I'm trying to do, is make the TextInput widget opaque so 
        ##that you can't see the frame and only the text is visible

''')

class TestWidgetsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Proj'
        return root_widget

TestWidgetsApp().run()
```

Comment: Consider setting the background color of your ExampleScreen and setting the background color of your TextInput to the same color

Comment: If you don't want to set the background_color you can alternatively set the background_normal and the background_active images to ''

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`background_color`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.background_color) property and set alpha chanel to 0:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class ExampleScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ExampleManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
ExampleManager:
    ExampleScreen:

<ExampleScreen>:
    name: 'example_screen'
    TextInput:
        id: t_1
        text: 'Test text in input 1'
        size_hint: .5, .5
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .5}
        multiline: True
        readonly: True
        foreground_color: (1,0,1,1)
        background_color: (0,0,0,0)

    TextInput:
        id: t_2
        text: 'Test text in input 2'
        size_hint: .5, .5
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
        multiline: True
        readonly: True
        foreground_color: (1,1,0,1)
        background_color: (0,0,0,0)

''')

class TestWidgetsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Proj'
        return root_widget

TestWidgetsApp().run()
```

[image]